# How to make a single column scrollable?

Tags: r, shiny

Im working on a R shiny app. It consists of 3 columns. Column 1 is the search criteria and column 3 are output graphs.
Center column has multiple tables which require the user to scroll down. I would like to have this panel be scrollable while maintaining the rest of the page static. Is this possible?

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    
    HTML("<title>Mipres</title>"),
    
    tags$style(
    
      
      HTML(".shiny-notification {
             position:fixed;
             top: calc(0%);
             left: calc(90%);
             }
             "
      )
      ),
    ), 
    img(src = "saludmia-s.png", height = 110, width = 250),
  
  titlePanel(
    h1("Informes", align = "center")),            

    hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"),
    #br(),
 
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           titlePanel(h3("Parametros de busqueda")),
       titlePanel(h4("Fecha")),

           verbatimTextOutput("date_max"),
           airDatepickerInput(
             inputId = "date1",
             #label = "Select range of dates:",
             range = F, 
             autoClose = T,
             value = Sys.Date()-14 ,
                    #   Sys.Date()),
             todayButton = F,
             clearButton = T,
             addon = c("none")
            ),
           
           airDatepickerInput(
             inputId = "date2",
             #label = "Select range of dates:",
             range = F, 
             autoClose = T,
             value = Sys.Date()+1 ,
             #   Sys.Date()),
             todayButton = F,
             clearButton = T,
             addon = c("none")
           ),
           
           div(style = "margin-top: -10px"),
           br(),
           radioButtons("radio1", 
                        label = h4("Criterios"),
                        choices = list("Direccionado" = 1),#,
                                       #"Direccionado - No entregado" = 2,
                                       #"Direccionado - Entregado - No Facturado" = 3,
                                       #"Direccionado - Entregado - Facturado" = 4,
                                       #"Solo facturado" = 5), 
                        selected = 1),
          
           
           br(),
           br(),
           
       #Processing Button
           actionButton("gobutton1", label =  "Procesar"),

           style='border-right: 1px solid gray'),
   
     
    
    column(7,
           
           style='border-right: 1px solid gray',
           h3("Direccionamientos totales para el periodo"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
           br(),
           h3("Entregas programadas segun direccionamiento"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table2"),
           br(),
           h3("Entregas reportadas segun direccionamiento"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table3"),           
           br(),
           h3("Facturacion reportada segun direccionamiento"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table4"),     
           style=""),
            
   column(2,

           plotlyOutput('plot')

           )
    
    
  ),
  
    

)
```

Comment: Try this https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick here is to use boxes from the `shinydashboard` package to create separate divs within the fluid columns. For the middle box that holds your long table you can set the box height to fill the vertical extent of the screen then add `overflow-y:scroll` to the style parameters to add your scroll bar. For the boxes you want static just make sure the objects inside of them (e.g., plots or input widgets) are not taller than the screen size by setting your height parameter in your `plotOutput()` function to something like 85% of screen height to account for the header and such. See the example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) # for box()
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    h1("Informes", align = "center")),
    hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"),
  
  column(width = 2,
         titlePanel(h3("Parametros de busqueda")),
         titlePanel(h4("Fecha")),
         box(
           shinyWidgets::airDatepickerInput(
             inputId = "date1",
             range = F, 
             autoClose = T,
             value = Sys.Date()-14 ,
             todayButton = F,
             clearButton = T,
             addon = c("none")
           ),
           
           shinyWidgets::airDatepickerInput(
             inputId = "date2",
             range = F, 
             autoClose = T,
             value = Sys.Date() + 1 ,
             todayButton = F,
             clearButton = T,
             addon = c("none")
           ),
           
           div(style = "margin-top: -10px"),
           br(),
           radioButtons("radio1", 
                        label = h4("Criterios"),
                        choices = list("Direccionado" = 1,
                        "Otra cosa" = 2,
                        "Otra cosa mas" = 3),
                        selected = 1),
           br(),
           actionButton("gobutton1", label = "Procesar")
         )
  ),
         
  column(width = 5,
         box(style='overflow-y:scroll; height:85vh; min-width:40vw;',
           DTOutput('table')
         )
  ),
  
  column(width = 5,
         box(style = 'height:85vh; min-width:40vw;',
             plotOutput("plot", height = '85vh')
         )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    # some dummy data
    time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,7),each = 7))
    value <- runif(49, 10, 100)             
    group <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],times = 7)
    data <- data.frame(time, value, group)
    
    # stacked area chart
    ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
      geom_area()
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(mtcars,
       options = list(paging = FALSE)
       )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[app with middle scroll column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nusQ7.png)